# Combining Tables from Multiple Databases

Tags: sql, database, schema, ssms, aggregation

I have 100+ databases and I created a new one where I want to combine 30 tables from each database into 30 aggregated tables in the new DB. The tables have the same theme as in db1.tb1 = db2.tb1, but not different tables from each other like db1.tb1 NE db1.tb2.

I would like to combine them with a loop so I can do this routinely. I have read numerous other posts and they're either overly complex or unanswered. Is this possible and if so, what would it look like?

Google, research, SE, SQL commands trial and error.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using